# How to pass dynamic parameters to flutter web app

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

I have a flutter web app hosted on a domain name, [www.abc.com](http://www.abc.com). I want to add a random user guid to the apps url link like [www.abc.com/2f02163f-fd44-4904-88a0-11a6fcae8148](http://www.abc.com/2f02163f-fd44-4904-88a0-11a6fcae8148) from another web app to open a web page. The guid will be generated from another site, [www.bcd.com](http://www.bcd.com), which when user clicks a link from it will be redirected to my other domain with a guid attached to the app as [www.abc.com/2f02163f-fd44-4904-88a0-11a6fcae8148](http://www.abc.com/2f02163f-fd44-4904-88a0-11a6fcae8148). How can I set the route in flutter to open a webpage using random guids attached to the domain name [www.abc.com](http://www.abc.com) .

I have tried using ongenerate routes but it aint working, i end up with a 404 error on flutter?

```
   class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'UMB PHIACompanion',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primaryColor: kPrimaryColor,
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.white,
      ),
  
      onGenerateRoute: generateRoute,
      navigatorObservers: [routeObserver],
    );
  }

  static Route<dynamic> generateRoute(RouteSettings settings) {
    switch (settings.name) {
      case '/':
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => HomeScreenDesktop());
      default:
        return MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (_) => Scaffold(
              body: Center(
                  child: Text('No route defined for ${settings.name}')),
            ));
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: use `onGenerateRoute` instead of `routes:` array

Comment: Hi @Dude can you show with an example, whatever am doing aint working, have edited what I have so far but aint working when deployed to a server